# How to Copy file to new location when script having issues

Tags: powershell, hash, copy

I was trying to populated hashes using the PowerShell `Get-FileHash` but it gives an error.

```
Get-FileHash "C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log" -Algorithm sha256 | Format-List
```

This is the error:

> Get-FileHash : The file 'C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log' cannot be read:
>   The process cannot access the file 'C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log'
>   because it is being used by another process.

So, I'm trying to copy the file to another location.

How can I do it?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Do you have more details of exactly what you're doing that fails, especially any code?

Comment: The error told that the file is currently locked and unable to access. So i wanted to copy those file to specific location so that it is not locked

Comment: Please paste the error code to your question. Also, add the code you are running.

Comment: Get-FileHash "C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log" -Algorithm sha256 | Format-List

This is the code 

Get-FileHash : The file 'C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log' cannot be read: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Intel\Logs\IntelCPHS.log' because it is being used by 
another process.